# I don't understand the `get` keyword for getters in JS class declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a JS class.

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width) {
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
    }
    // Getter
    get area() {
      return this.calcArea();
    }
    // Method
    calcArea() {
      return this.height * this.width;
    }
  }

  const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

  console.log(square.area); // 100
```

It seems to work fine. However, I don't understand why we need to specify the `get` keyword for `area()` but not for `calcArea()` although both are returning values. Could someone explain this? And if possible, if someone could also explain this from react's perspective and whether this still applies for class components? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: The only real difference is that `area` will invoke and return the value when `.area` is *referenced*, whereas `calcArea` will only run when the function is explicitly invoked with `()`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay, got it! But why would I ever need to reference a method like that, when I can simply invoke it?

Comment: It can be used to hide implementation details. Sometimes you might like that, though IMO often you wouldn't, since it can make things a bit confusing. Eg `.innerHTML` is a getter/setter.